# Correct display of Search list REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am unable to display the search list the way i would like to . The list is stuck on the page before i even start using the search bar . I want the list to only display if the user inputs and once they do the list should be nice and neat , not how it currently looks .

Here is the sandbox .  https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-keller-z2gy32?file=/src/components/Header.js:145-1307 The search feature is within the header . I have attempted to use the  tags and it makes no difference as the list is on the page upon start of all the items .

```
export default function Header() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [allitems, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products")
      .then((res) => {
        setItems(res.data.products);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Header">
      <h1> Header </h1>
      <Link to="/">
        <button className="btnhome"> Home </button>
      </Link>
      {/* <input className = "searchbar"></input> */}
      <div>
        {/*  give your quert state as value and update it on change*/}
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter item to be searched"
          value={query}
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        {/*filter it by title before mapping*/}
        {allitems
          .filter((item) => item.title.search(query) !== -1)
          .map((item) => (
            <div>
              <Link to={`${item.title}`}>
                <h1 key={item.id}> {item.title} </h1>
              </Link>
              <h1>{item.title}</h1>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I assume the problem here is that the items show up before you type in any search words.

All items pass the filter when the query string is "".

You could hide the list if the query is === ""

```js
{query !== "" &&  allitems.filter((item) => item.title.search(query) !== -1)
    .map((item) => (
        <div>
            <Link to={`${item.title}`}>
                <h1 key={item.id}> {item.title} </h1>
            </Link>
            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
        </div>
    ))
}
```

For extra points you could even filter the items before the render

```js
export default function Header() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [allitems, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products")
      .then((res) => {
        setItems(res.data.products);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const filteredItems = useMemo(() => {
    if (query === "") return [];
    return allitems.filter(
      (item) => item.title.toLowerCase().search(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    ); // toLowerCase() to not care about case sensitivity
  }, [query, allitems]); // this will rerun when either query or allitems is changes

  return (
    <div className="Header">
      <h1> Header </h1>
      <Link to="/">
        <button className="btnhome"> Home </button>
      </Link>
      {/* <input className = "searchbar"></input> */}
      <div>
        {/*  give your quert state as value and update it on change*/}
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter item to be searched"
          value={query}
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        {/*filter it by title before mapping*/}
        {filteredItems.map((item) => (
          <div>
            <Link to={`${item.title}`}>
              <h1 key={item.id}> {item.title} </h1>
            </Link>
            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it is still rendering without background e.g if i try to search on the phones page then it renders ontop of the other products on the page if that makes sense

Comment: Yes, that is because you have not added any styling to the <div>

Comment: i tried every alternative to no avail . please take a look

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-keller-z2gy32?file=/src/styles.css IVE added classnames